# Mod security syntax error

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security

when i ran the command `apache2ctl configtest` it is showing this error

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 193 of /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf:
ModSecurity: Failed to open the audit log file: /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
```

and on line 193

```
SecAuditLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
```

what is wrong? can anyone tell why is it so

Comment: Look for the file and its containing directory.

Comment: Look for what ?

Comment: Look for everything. Whether they exist, what their permissions and ownership are, anything unusual.

Comment: it does not exist

Comment: Which does not exist? The file or the directory? You were meant to look at both.

Comment: var/log/apache2 exists but modsec_audit.log doesn't

Comment: You forgot to look at the ownership and permissions too!

Comment: when i restarted the log file is there , and the permission is `-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Dec  5 18:44 /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log`

Comment: Ok so root can write to it. Does Apache run as root? Usually the main Apache process runs as root (to grab port 80 and 443 which requires extra permissions)but the other processes do not (for security reasons). So sounds like you need to fix the permissions.

Comment: Having the same issue.. what should be the permissions? And how to add them? Thx

Answer (score 1):

I was almost two years late to this post but in my case it is because I was executing the command without administrator privileges. try with sudo apachectl -t or sudo apache2ctl configtest